# Flutter desktop release

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I had developed a Flutter desktop app by using firebase packages, but when I write command ( flutter build windows ) to release my desktop app showing this big errors:

Noted: bttc it's my project name.

```
nal.dir_Debug_cord_rep_btree.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter [D:\bttc\build\windows\runner\bttc.vcxproj]
firebase_firestore.lib(ea039456823ba76e9082b438a5fcc026_grpc.dir_Debug_alts_tsi_handshaker.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter [D:\bttc\build\windows\runner\bttc.vcxproj]
```

Comment: Firebase is not supported on Windows per this comment: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10171#issuecomment-1379685823. Is this the first time you running the app on Windows?